# google pageSpeed Insights, javascript IS loaded below the fold WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, w3-total-cache

I'm a WordPress user with lots of scripts and styles that are render-blocking.

Google's PageSpeed Insights is telling me that I have a ton of scripts above the fold, but when I look in my console they are being loaded right above the /body tag.

For example, the last script loaded above the closing body tag looks like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=3.9.2"></script>
  <div id="wpadminbar" class="" role="navigation"></div>
  <div id="tiptip_holder" style="max-width:290px;"></div>
  <iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="display: none;"></iframe>
  <div id="window-resizer-tooltip" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
```

How is this last script considered above the fold?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a javaScript function to load your external javaScript code.
Then use

```
window.onload = function;
```

where "fucntion is the name of your load function.

Of course check you `<head>` for other js.

You should generate an HAR HTTP Archive for the page load.  You could use Google Chrome's Timeline recorder. There is an online guide to using the Timeline reorder but there is a fairly steep learning curve. It will give you every detail you need and a lot more.

How to record: [Link to How to Record](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline#making-a-recording)

Easier, but with less detail, is using webpagetest.org to generate the HAR for you.
After you get the Page Speed test summary, in the upper right hand corner there is a link labeled "Export HTTP Archive (.har)".

Then use PHP to analyze the HAR.  This is rather crude, but it is quick and easy.

```
$data = @file_get_contents($path);
$json = json_decode($data,true);
echo '<pre>
var_export($json );
echo '</pre>
```

What you want to observe is when your .js loads with respect to other content start load times.